# Select multiple items from dropdown and send to database

Tags: php, sql, database, wordpress, forms

I have a form with this field in it. Which calls from a skills table that has 2 columns - the skill_id(int) and the skill(varchar). I want the user to choose multiple choices for the skills they have and add this to their information but only 1 choice is going through.

```
print ("<tr><td valign=top>Skill: </td><td><select name=uskill_id[0] size=3 multiple=multiple>");


  global $wpdb;
  $trade = $wpdb->get_results("select skill, skill_id from wp_skill", ARRAY_A);
  foreach($trade as $row) {
      $skill = $row['skill'];
      $skill_id  = $row['skill_id'];
      print '<option value="'.$skill_id.'">'.$skill.'</option>';
}
```

Here is the insert statement which will send the info to the database. The skill_id I have turned into a varchar type from an int type but still no luck.

```
global $wpdb; $success=$wpdb->insert('trades', array('skill_id' => explode(', ', $_POST['uskill_id[0]'])));
```

Comment: Instead of Dropdown, use check box to select multiple options. or check the value of `$_POST['uskill_id[0]']`

Comment: The problem is sending the array with multiple values to a column either as a string or an int.

Comment: I'm also getting this warning - Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in \wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1092

Answer (score 0):

```
<"?php          if($_POST){
                $uskill_id              =   implode(", ",$_POST['uskill_id']);

                echo $uskill_id;//to data base          } ?>
```

use this form

```
            <label for="uskill_id" >Skils </label><br/>

            <select name="uskill_id[]"   id="uskill_id" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Click to select..." >
           <option value="1">English Writing </option>
            <option value="2">Blog Writing </option>
             <option value="3">Article  Writing </option>
              <option value="4">Book Writing </option>

           </select>


       <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

         `
```